# Maya skeleton smooth bind

Tags: modeling, maya

I have a problem with rigging in maya.
I have a skeleton that I smooth bound to the model.
The normal position of the legs are this:

[image]

But when I move the controler on the left foot, the skin on the right leg moves along with it.

[image]

I have used a point constraint on the controler for the IK handle on the leg.
I have tried weight painting the skin but it stays the same.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Maybe [graphicdesign.se] or [gamedev.se]?

Comment: I didnt know about the graphic design section.
Thank you I will remove my question from here

Comment: See you over there! :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to replace the influences from the right leg on the left leg, then Mirror the skin(+X to -X)...